# Some of my Panel content is missing for anonymous users. What went wrong?

Tags: 7, panels

I've set up a landing page panel with two items in it, a content page with a welcome message and a view showing certain content. It works great, but when I look at it as an anonymous user only the view is showing up, not the welcome page message.

I haven't put any special access conditions and my only variant is the landing page and I can see all the content in the preview, so I don't understand why it isn't visible to everyone. The welcome message is on a published page as well, and caching is disabled for that panel for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was a caching issue after all. >.<

I'm not sure which caches Panels uses, but the very handy [Administration menu](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu)'s flush all caches link seems to have fixed the problem.